# cross validation for distribution

Tags: distributions, forecasting, cross-validation, density-estimation

Assume we have a linear regression model. Then, assume we have response values $y_{1}, \dots, y_{n}$ and covariates vectors $\textbf{x}_{1}, \dots, \textbf{x}_{n}$. To assess the prediction performance we can, for example, use leave-one-out cross validation to estimate mean squared error:
$$
MSE = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y}_{i}^{\backslash i} - y_{i}),
$$
where for a given model $\hat{y}_{i}^{\backslash i}$ is the estimated response on covariate $\textbf{x}_{i}$ without $\textbf{x}_{i}$ in model fitting.

Assume we want to assess forecasting ability for discrete distribution. What should we do? What is "the error" in this case?

Comment: Did you intend $MSE = \frac 1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y}_{i}^{\backslash i} - y_{i})^2$ or something similar?  Taking the square root of this , so a sort of RMSE, would be on the same scale as the original data

Comment: something similar in idea. How would it work for estimation of a discrete distribution? I haven't found much written about it...

Comment: A discrete distribution for example on the integers? If your $\hat{y}_{i}^{\backslash i}$ are integers then this would still work (averages of integers do not have to be integers).  If you really wanted to ask about how to make $\hat{y}_{i}^{\backslash i}$ an integer in regression, then that is a different question

Comment: Nothing about the formula you give or the underlying procedure makes assumptions about the distribution: it applies the same way for continuous and discrete distributions of any of the quantities involved.

Comment: I meant how to assess the forecasting ability of an estumator of discrete distribution. The support is not necessarily  integers...

Comment: That still is not a distinction made in the notation or theory.  There is a potential concern about how to measure prediction accuracy: but there are a huge number of possible answers to that, because they depend on the nature of the data and the application.